# Inheritance chain in state machine branching out

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a state machine to controll ai behaviour in Unity 3D. 
My question is regarding inheritance. Im trying to set up some base logic that handles how and why states shoul be changed. But further down the inheritance line i need different kind of characters to be able to do character speicfic things. But im not able to do this with inheritnance.

Can someone confirm that my thinking is not how its done? then i know to find another solution.

PSEUDO CODE:

```
        // STATE CONTROLLERS CONTROLL THE CHARACETER BY CHOOSING WITCH STATE THEY SHOULD BE IN 

abstract class StateController {
    StateBase state;
    int HitPoints;
    int Hunger:

    abstract void Update()
    {
            CheckIfStateShouldChange();
            state.UpdateState(this);
    }
}

WolfStateController : StateController {

    WolfState state; 

    override void Update()
    {
    base.Update();
    state.Update(this);
    }
}

SheepStateController : StateController {

    SheepState state; 

    override void Update()
    {
    base.Update();
    state.Update(this);
    }
}

    // STATES CONTAINS LOGIC FOR BEHAVIOUR IN A CERTAIN STATE
StateBase {

        virtual void UpdateState( StateController controller)
        {

        // Does things all inheriting classes should do

        }
    }

WolfState : StateBase {

        override void UpdateState( WolfStateController wolfstate)
        { 
        base.UpdateState(WolfStateController wolfstate)
            //Does wolf specific things that needs to be done in all WolfStates
        }
}

WolfStalkAndHuntState : WolfState {

        override void UpdateState( WolfStateController wolfstate)
        {       
            base.UpdateState(WolfStateController wolfState);
            //Hunts sheep and attacks on sight
        }
    }

SheepState : StateBase {

        override void UpdateState( SheepStateController sheepState)
        { 
            //Does sheepy things
        }
    }

SheepReproduceState : SheepState {

        override void UpdateState( SheepStateController sheepState)
        {       
            base.UpdateState(SheepStateController sheepState);
            // Looks for mate and gets freaky
        }
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear when looking at you pseudo code why your base class isn't enough. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Also I don't see why you need to create a child class for every single character type. You should use your controller with more abstraction, simply calling the necessary update phases and a reference to an abstract character that hold every necessary data. Tell me if you want me to elaborate

Comment: Instead of inheritance, you might want to consider using a strategy pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

Controller Class:

public class SoliderController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public sState currentState;

```
[HideInInspector] public FireState fireState;
[HideInInspector] public IdleState idleState;
[HideInInspector] public ChaseState chaseState;


private void Awake()
{
    fireState = new FireState(this);
    idleState = new IdleState(this);
    chaseState = new ChaseState(this);
}

private void Start ()
{
    currentState = idleState;
}

private void Update()
{
    currentState.Update();
}
```

Interface:

```
public abstract class sState
{
public abstract void Update();
public abstract void ToChaseState();
public abstract void ToIdleState();
public abstract void ToFireState();
}
```

Example Class

```
public class IdleState : sState
{
private readonly SoliderController controller;


public IdleState(SoliderController soliderController)
{
    controller = soliderController;
}

public override void Update()
{

    Patrol();

    //Condition to change state
    if (*expresion1*)
        ToChaseState();
    if (*expresion2*)
        ToFireState();
}

private void Patrol()
{
      //Your Logic for the behvaiour wanted.
}

public override void ToChaseState()
{
    controller.currentState = controller.chaseState;
}

public override void ToFireState()
{
    controller.currentState = controller.fireState;
}

public override void ToIdleState()
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Can't transition to same state");
}
}
```

This way checking for changes is way easier and also you can impletement state specific behaviours as well. Also, adding a new state goes really easy, you just implement the new Class and ToNewState method in the interface.

Hope it helped.